# How to implement extension method Shuffle like List's Reverse without return?

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods, reverse, shuffle

I have the following code for Shuffle so far,

```
    public static IList<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        return list.OrderBy(element => rnd.Next());
    }
```

and i use it like,

```
    list = list.Shuffle();
```

i want to be able to use it like

```
    list.Shuffle(); // like list.Reverse();
```

so basically i want to shuffle by reference

I tried the following code,

```
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this ref IList<T> list)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        list.OrderBy(element => rnd.Next());
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this quite some time ago. Probably worth checking that it is true to the linked algorithm. These sorts of thing are notoriously easy to get subtly wrong.

```
    //Fisher-Yates_shuffle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> RandomThreadLocal =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int seed = -1)
    {
        var r = seed >= 0 ? new Random(seed) : RandomThreadLocal.Value;
        var len = list.Count;
        for (var i = len - 1; i >= 1; --i)
        {
            var j = r.Next(i);
            var tmp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

As per comments below, could be overloaded for more flexibility:

```
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> RandomThreadLocal =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int seed)
    {
        list.Shuffle(new Random(seed));
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        list.Shuffle(null);
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, Random rand)
    {
        var r = rand ?? RandomThreadLocal.Value;

        var len = list.Count;
        for (var i = len - 1; i >= 1; --i)
        {
            var j = r.Next(i);
            var tmp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also like providing an overload (possibly in addition to others) that passes in an existing `Random` instance.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this algorithm is also more efficient than the one in the OP.  It's O(n) rather than O(n * log(n)).

Comment: The Shuffle algorithm implementation(s) above have an error. Random.Next(int maxValue) is an exclusive upper bound but you want it inclusive.  Just replace var j = r.Next(i); with var j = r.Next(i + 1);  and your good to go.

Comment: @Keith ... Well done for taking me to my word. "subtly wrong" indeed!